# How can I determine if the sequence $\frac{n^{2} + 3^{n}}{n^{4} + 2^{n}}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the sequence $\frac{n^{2} + 3^{n}}{n^{4} + 2^{n}}$ converges. If it converges find the limit and if it diverges determine whether it has an infinite limit.

*Proof:* let $a_{n} = \frac{n^{2} + 3^{n}}{n^{4} + 2^{n}}$

Divide by $n^{2}$  so you have $\frac{1+\frac{3^n}{n^2}}{\frac{2^{n}}{n^{2}}+n^{2}}$

Therefore it converges to 0 ?

Is that right?

Comment: and the limit is 0?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: in $(n^2+3^n)/(2^n+n^4)\to 0$, note the $3^n$ term.

Answer (score 0):

Exponentials grow more quickly than polynomials, so when both the numerator and the denominator are the sum of a polynomial and an exponential, you look at the bases of the exponentials and ignore the polynomials.

As n-> ∞, $(3^n+n^2)/(2^n+n^4)≈(3/2)^n$

Answer (score 0):

your sequence is equivalent to $a_n=\frac{\frac{n^2}{2^n}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n}{1+\frac{n^4}{2^n }}$ this goes to infinity for $n$ tends to infinity